# Connect to SQL Server Database using Pycharm (pyodbc)

Tags: python, sql-server, python-2.7, pycharm, pyodbc

I can access my SQL Server via SQL Server Mgmt Studio located at

```
<IP_ADDRESS> with credentials:
<USERID>
<PWD>
```

Using pycharm with Anaconda 2.7 as the interpreter my code is:

```
import pyodbc as p

server = '<IP_ADDRESS>'
database = 'listOfDBs/DB'
username = '<USERID>'
password = '<PWD>'

print ("DB CONNECT ATTEMPT")
try:
    cnxn = p.connect(
        'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
    print ("SUCCESS")
except Exception as e:
    print ("Error: " + str(e))
```

My SQL Server is setup as:

```
ListOfDBs/DB
Folder1
Folder2
Folder3
Folder3
```

How do I connect to DB in ListOfDBs?

If I do:

```
Server = "XX.XXX.XXX/listOfDbs"
Database = "DB"
```

I get :

```
('08001', u'[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied. (17) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()). (53)')
```

If I do:

```
Server = "XX.XXX.XXX"
Database = "listOfDBs/DB"
```

I get:

```
('42000', u'[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "listOfDBs/DB" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "listOfDBs/DB" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060)')
```

How do I do this? I am using Pycharm community version.